# SQL Taking a Date in related group and use it to fill date nulls within the same group

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to fill in NULL Start Dates by finding the one date that is shown and using that date within the Numeric Date Group. What I have is this:

| Order ID | Numeric Date | Numeric Date ID | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.01 | 7/25/2021 |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.02 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.03 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.05 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.02 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.03 | 8/7/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.05 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.05 | NULL |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.05 | NULL |

What I would like is this:

| Order ID | Numeric Date | Numeric Date ID | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934 | 7/25/2021 |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.01 | 7/25/2021 |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.02 | 7/25/2021 |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.03 | 7/25/2021 |
| 478421 | 65934 | 65934.05 | 7/25/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967 | 8/7/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.02 | 8/7/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.03 | 8/7/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.05 | 8/7/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.05 | 8/7/2021 |
| 478421 | 65967 | 65967.05 | 8/7/2021 |

Note that the Numeric Date is not the same as Start Date so using dateadd(day, [Numeric Date], '1840-12-31') to find the date to CASE statement is not going to work. This is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[Order ID]
,LEFT([Numeric Date ID], 5) 'Numeric Date'
,[Numeric Date ID]
,[Start Date]

FROM Orders
WHERE [Order ID] = '478421'
```

Comment: If there is a single/one not null “start date” per order, “numeric date” then  `min\max([Start Date]) over(partition by [Order ID], [Numeric Date])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple window function looks like it should do the trick

```sql
SELECT
  o.[Order ID],
  CAST(o.[Numeric Date ID] AS int) [Numeric Date],
  o.[Numeric Date ID],
  MIN(o.[Start Date]) OVER (
      PARTITION BY o.[Order ID], CAST(o.[Numeric Date ID] AS int)) [Start Date]
FROM Orders o;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://%5BNumeric%20Date%20ID%5D)

Instead of doing `LEFT` on `[Numeric Date ID]` it seems better to just cast it to `int`.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface - worked perfectly. And yes, CAST as INT is better.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach:

```
--Get list of Numeric Date -> Start Date
WITH dates_cte AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    [Numeric Date],
    [Start Date]
  FROM dbo.MyTable
)
SELECT
  MyTable.[Order ID]
  MyTable.[Numeric Date]
  MyTable.[Numeric Date ID]
  AllDates.[Start Date]
FROM dbo.MyTable MyTable
JOIN dates_cte AllDates
ON MyTable.[Numeric Date] = AllDates.[Numeric Date]
```

Comment: Thank you, Andreas. I tested this and the granularity isn't specific enough. This returns approximately 150K rows. I see what you are suggesting and will tweak it to get it to work.